# I want to get object_id that created by the worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jobs, sidekiq, worker

I make a queue system for my rails app to create an object

in the conreoller.rb

```
  def create
  object = CreateApplicationJob.perform_later
   end
```

in the CreateApplicationJob.rb file

```
def perform(*args)  
     = Object.create!(name: params[:name])
end
```

I want to get the created object.id

Comment: You want to get the created `object.id` when? Where? In that `create` method? Because, naturally, that's not the way it works. And, out of curiosity, what's that `=` for in front of `Object.create!`?

Answer (score 2):

You're using a queue, so the Object won't be created until the job is processed.

A queue is best used for processes that aren't time sensitive (sending a batch of emails, refreshing data from an external API, etc.); in this case it sounds like you want the object to be available immediately, in which case a queue is not appropriate:

```rb
def create
  object = Object.create!(name: params[:name])
  # object.id => 3
end
```

Based on your comments, it sounds like your concern is race conditions resulting in the name not being unique. In that case, you'll want to use a uniqueness constraint in the database. This can be added with a migrate, using the following call:

```rb
add_index :objects, :name, unique: true
```

You could also use table locking, but Rails doesn't provide an API for this so you'd need to use raw SQL.

---

Side note: I'm assuming that you're just using `Object` as a placeholder for your model name, but just in case: `Object` is the default root of all Ruby objects so you shouldn't override it as an ActiveRecord model.

Comment: No , I don't want object to be available immediately , I just want it's id whenever it's available

Comment: I made this queue to ensure never creation of 2 objects with the same name

Comment: You don't need a queue to ensure that `name` is unique. That's the job for a validation (front end, application, database, etc.). There are lots of excellent reasons for using queues. That doesn't seem like one of them. But, perhaps I'm missing a key piece of the puzzle.

Comment: validation just check if the name already exist or not , but 
if 2 requests are sent together validation may not catch name similarity

Comment: @Rana I've updated my answer to cover uniqueness constraints and table locking which should solve the race condition you're describing.